# Como posso calcular os elementos em Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso pegar o valor `id="valorPorcentagem"` que é o valor da porcentagem com o `(id="valor_vendedor")` e somar automaticamente no `id="comissao"`.

Sendo que:

```
valorPorcentagem / 100 x valor_vendedor = comissao
20 / 100 x 800,00 = 160,00
45 / 100 x 700,00 = 315,00
```

O valor total da comissão = **R$ 475,00**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<b>Comissão do Vendedor:</b>
<input type="text" name="total" id="comissao" readonly>
<br><br>

<select id="valorPorcentagem">
  <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
</select>

<input id="valor_vendedor" onkeyup="calcular()">
```

## javascript

```
function calcular() {
    var soma = $('.calcular').get().reduce(function(soma, el) {
        return (parseFloat(el.value.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", "."), 10) || 0) + soma;
    }, 0);

    soma = soma.toFixed(2);

    document.getElementById('comissao').value = soma;
    mascara(document.getElementById('comissao'), mreais);
}
```

O botão (Adicionar Plano) em HTML

```
<input type="text" name="usuarios[0][comissao_vendedor]" id="valor_vendedor" class="calcular form-control" placeholder="R$" onkeypress="mascara(this,mreais)" onkeyup="calcular()">
```

$ js

```
var AddTableRow = function(el) {
        var tbody = $(el).closest('table').find('tbody');
        var row = tbody.find('tr:last').clone();
        var name = row.find('.calcular').attr('name');
        var index = parseInt(name.match(/informacao\[(\d+)\]\[porcentagem\]/)[1], 10) + 1;
        row.find('[name^="informacao["]').each(function() {
            if (this.name) {
                this.name = this.name.replace(/^informacao\[\d+\]/, "informacao[" + index + "]");
            }
        });
        tbody.append(row);
    };
```

## [Segue o código](http://codepen.io/maurodenison/pen/wgPVLp)

Comment: Cadê `id=valorPorcentagem`?

Comment: Foi mau @MagicHat esqueci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sei que não foi o enfoque principal da pergunta, mas vi que ira trabalhar com mais de um campo `input`, portanto vai uma versão de como você poderia trabalhar:

**Cabem adaptações.**

```js
function calcular() {
  contador = 1;
  elementos = [];
  // Procuro todos elementos que possuem o pseudo-metodo "fazparte" e que estao visiveis no formulario
  jQuery('input[fazparte]:visible').each(function() {
    // Teoricamente os campos adicionados dinamicamente devem possuir id 
    // diferenciado, por um contador talvez? enfim, uso esse contador para
    // adicionar em um array que irei usar futuramente para fazer o calculo
    if (jQuery(this)[0].value != "") {
      elementos.push(contador);
    }
    contador++;
  });
  var valorFinal = 0;
  for (var i in elementos) {
    // Para cada input que possui valor, faco uma somatória das porcentagens 
    //dos elementos que possuem um valor setado, e jogo no valor final da comissão
    valorFinal += ((document.getElementById("porcentagem"+elementos[i]).value)/100)*(document.getElementById("valor"+elementos[i]).value)
  }
  document.getElementById("comissao").value = valorFinal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<b>Comissão do Vendedor:</b>
<input type="text" name="total" id="comissao" readonly>
<br>
<br>

<select id="porcentagem1" onchange="calcular()">
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
</select>

<input id="valor1" onblur="calcular()" fazparte>
<br/>
<select id="porcentagem2" onchange="calcular()">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
</select>

<input id="valor2" onblur="calcular()" fazparte>
```

---

Para adicionar elementos dinamicamente:

```js
function calcular() {
  contador = 1;
  elementos = [];
  jQuery('input[fazparte]:visible').each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this)[0].value != "") {
      elementos.push(contador);
    }
    contador++;
  });
  var valorFinal = 0;
  for (var i in elementos) {
    valorFinal += ((document.getElementById("porcentagem" + elementos[i]).value) / 100) * (document.getElementById("valor" + elementos[i]).value)
  }
  document.getElementById("comissao").value = valorFinal;
}

function adicionarElemento() {
  var contador = 0;
  jQuery('input[fazparte]:visible').each(function() {
    contador++;
  });
  // Aqui a logica de adicionar um proximo elemento para
  // funcionar na logica acima so sera necessario criar o proximo id corretamente, 
  // desse modo mesmo que o input
  // existir, se ele nao for setado, nao vai alterar em nada o valor da comissao
  var elemento = '<br/><select id="porcentagem' + (contador + 1) + '" onchange="calcular()"><option value="10">10</option><option value="45">45</option></select><input id="valor' + (contador + 1) + '" onblur="calcular()" fazparte>';
  $("#valor" + (contador)).after(elemento);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<b>Comissão do Vendedor:</b>
<input type="text" name="total" id="comissao" readonly>
<button onclick="adicionarElemento()">Adicionar plano</button>
<br>
<br>

<select id="porcentagem1" onchange="calcular()">
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
</select>

<input id="valor1" onblur="calcular()" fazparte>
<br/>
<select id="porcentagem2" onchange="calcular()">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
</select>

<input id="valor2" onblur="calcular()" fazparte>
```

Comment: Coloquei a função do Botão (Adicionar Plano), talvez seja aqui o problema.

Comment: Conforme a imagem acima, eu to pegando o valor da porcentagem (20) colocando o valor (800,00) e em Valor da Comissão exibe o valor dessa porcentagem, mas quando eu adiciono mais um plano pra poder escolher outra porcentagem (45) e (700,00) ele teria que somar o resultado.

Answer (score 2):

Mudei algumas coisas no código que você disponibilizou. Não entendi o uso do `reduce` e de uma função de máscara que não existe. Mas para efetuar esse cálculo, você pode simplesmente obter os valores usando `val()` e realizar a operação:

```js
function calcular() {
  var comissao = (parseFloat($("#valorPorcentagem").val())/100) * parseFloat($("#valor_vendedor").val());
  $("#comissao").val(comissao);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="valorPorcentagem">
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
</select>

<input id="valor_vendedor" onkeyup="calcular()">
<b>Comissão do Vendedor:
</b>
<input type="text" name="total" id="comissao" readonly>
```

Comment: Pegou o valor da porcentagem, mas não somou o total em id="comissao"

Comment: Qual total @MauroSantos? No código postado tem somente um `input`.

Comment: Na Comissão Vendedor ele soma automático quando eu adiciono mais um input

Answer (score 0):

Se vale mudar o HTML, podes sempre fazer um selector que selecione todos os elementos quando um desses é mudado, calcular a percentagem do mesmo, reduzir a lista à soma dos mesmos e apresentar o resultado num input:

```js
$.fn.reduce = [].reduce;

$('body').on('change', 'calc-comissao input' ,function(event, something) {
var total = $('calc-comissao input')
  .map(function(index, ele) { 
   return (ele.parentNode.querySelector('select').value / 100) * ele.value; 
  })
  .reduce(function(last, value) { return parseFloat(last) + parseFloat(value)});
  $('comissao input').val(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<b>Comissão do Vendedor:</b>
<comissao><input type=text/></comissao>

<hr/>
<calc-comissao>
  <select>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="40">40</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" value=0/>
</calc-comissao>
<br/>

<calc-comissao>
  <select>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="70">70</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" value=0/>
</calc-comissao>
<br/>
```